# Access iomega StorCenter ix4-200d dump utility from SSH

Tags: ssh, storage, network-attached-storage

My employer is in the process of returning a broken HDD to Lenovo/iomega. Unfortunately, before we can send it in, they require us to do a complete dump of the system's current state.

Normally, I would just go to "http:/diagnostics.html" and click a button to dump the whole thing to a tar.gz archive which I would then download and attach to my email to Lenovo support.

This, however, stopped working when we upgraded the firmware a couple days ago. Now it would just sit there for up to 30 minutes and pretend to collect the necessary logfiles.

I already tried manually launching "/usr/bin/gather". But since this wouldn't work either (it returned several messages about missing files and, strangely enough, would erase files such as index.html before it had even tared them, thus resulting in an early halt of the script), I'm no longer convinced that this would even be the correct utility.

Does anyone know more about iomega's dump mechanism and could help? Perhaps, it's simply a matter of executing another script beforehand?

Comment: I know what you are after, I get the question...but have you called Iomega support and simply told them "your dump via GUI isn't working...any other ideas?"  They might just say "send in the drive then, we'll figure it out"

Comment: Yea. That's exactly what my colleague told me, as well. I was just really hoping I could find this out myself. Anyways. I'm quite positive that it's due to sloppy scripting now (the "gather" script points to files inside /usr/bin that are actually in /usr/sbin and also tries to tar certain files after it has already removed them). Nothing I'd honestly want to fix for them. In short: I just dropped them a line.